# Canonical domain check failed with htaccess rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why does the following code (in the .htaccess file) work only for the home-page but not any other page? e.g. example.com/house. This did not work, namely I get a canonical domain check failure.

```
#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @Abhishek gurjar... error is "canonical domain check failure".

Comment: What is giving this error?